# Getting " can not invoke this.repositoryname is null" in grpc implementation with springboot

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, nullpointerexception, grpc

[image: Repository null error]
[image: Grpc implementation]

I have implemented GRPC in springboot application and getting error null and trying to connect with MySQL.
In personDetailImpl i have autowired the repository. And trying to fetch the data from database in impl class. But getting error.
[ " Can not invoke this.repository.methodname because this.repository is null. " ]

Can anyone have a solution how can we connect grpc with MySQL by autowiring repository.

Comment: Your class `PersonDetailImpl` is not marked with any annotation like `@Component` or `@Service` or something, so Spring IOC won't instantiate & initialize it.

Comment: Also, please copy-paste the formatted code, error stack-trace, etc. instead of attaching an image. It is much easier to search and copy-paste details from the question.

Comment: @ishan tried with service and component annotation. But still it's not working.

Comment: How is `PersonDetailImpl` object injected in `PersonsDetailsGrpc` class?  Copy-paste that code piece also (as formatted text, not image)

Comment: I have the same problem has anyone found a solution?