# How to create a repository without annotations

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, grpc-java

I'm creating a grpc client and server to communicate with my system but it's giving me this [error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76152279/getting-can-not-invoke-this-repositoryname-is-null-in-grpc-implementation-wit)  the service I instantiated in the constructor:

```
@Service
public class ServiceCategoryImpl extends CategoryProductGrpc.CategoryProductImplBase {
    private final CategoryCommandServiceImpl CategoryCommand;

    public ServiceCategoryImpl(){

        CategoryCommand = new CategoryCommandServiceImpl();
    }
}
```

But the repository is an interface if I extend it in a class I need to implement all the CrudRepository methods:

```
public interface CategoryRepository extends CrudRepository<Category, Long> {
    Category findBySlug(String slug);
    
}
```

So I thought of using EntityManagerFactory but I'm trying an error:

> jakarta.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for
> EntityManager named category

```
public class CategoryRepositoryImpl{
    public Category findBySlug(String slug) {

        EntityManagerFactory factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("category");
        EntityManager manager = factory.createEntityManager();
        return manager.find(Category.class, slug);
    }
}
```

Does anyone know where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

From your description, I've identified a few issues:

Firstly, is `CategoryCommandServiceImpl` annotated as a service with either `@Service` or `@Component`? If so, you should allow Spring to handle dependency injection for you. Here's an example of how your service might be defined:

```
@Service
public class ServiceCategoryImpl extends CategoryProductGrpc.CategoryProductImplBase {
    private final CategoryCommandServiceImpl CategoryCommand;

    // Constructor-based dependency injection
    public ServiceCategoryImpl(CategoryCommandServiceImpl CategoryCommand) {
        this.CategoryCommand = CategoryCommand;
    }
}
```

For more information on this topic, you can refer to the Spring documentation. Here's the dependency injection section in the [Spring docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/core/beans/dependencies/factory-collaborators.html).

> But the repository is an interface if I extend it in a class I need to
> implement all the CrudRepository methods

No, you don't need to, unless you're looking to override the default behavior. That interface serves as an abstraction provided by Spring Data, shielding you from the intricacies of specific database vendors. It enables the automatic creation of repository implementations at runtime based on a repository interface. I recommend diving deeper into this topic [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.core-concepts). For a hands-on understanding, refer to this basic example [here](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/).

Comment: My CategoryCommandServiceImpl class is @Service.

Comment: Are you telling me that even though I implement a class for the CrudRepository interface, I don't change the behavior of the methods? I wanted to use @Autoriwed but with the grpc class it doesn't work

Thanks for the feedback

Answer (score 0):

> But the repository is an interface if I extend it in a class I need to
> implement all the CrudRepository methods

The official way to extend spring-data 's repository interface is through implementing a custom repository.(See [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.single-repository-behavior)). You do not need to implement all `CrudRepository` 's method. Just implement the method that you want to have in a separate spring bean as usual and use `@PersistenceContext` to inject the `EntityManager`.

Something like :

```java
interface MyCustomCategoryRepository  {
  Category findBySlug(String slug);
}
```

```java
@Repository
class MyCustomCategoryRepositoryImpl implements MyCustomCategoryRepository {
  @PersistenceContext
  private EntityManager em;

  @Override
  Category findBySlug(String slug) {
      //your implementation
  }

}
```

And extend the normal `CategoryRepository` with your customized repository interface :

```java
interface CustomerRepository extends CrudRepository<Category, Long> , MyCustomCategoryRepository {

}
```

Comment: Perfect this works but which class do I instantiate without using @Autowired the MyCustomCategoryRepositoryImpl or CustomerRepository class? Thanks for the feedback

Comment: I tried to use the MyCustomCategoryRepositoryImpl repository but it gave me this error: `java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke \"jakarta.persistence.EntityManager.find(java.lang.Class, Object)\" because \"this.em\" is null` will be do grpc classes not support annotations?

Comment: Autowired `CustomerRepository` into the class that you want to use the repository. Also , you have to make sure  `MyCustomCategoryRepositoryImpl` is also a spring bean. Already update my answer about it . thanks.

Comment: `java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke \"com.example.categoryproductcommand.repository.impl.CustomerCategoryRepository.findBySlug(String)\" because \"this.categoryRepository\" is null`     `@Autowired
    private CustomerCategoryRepository categoryRepository;`

Comment: The error is the same every time when I want to use autoriwed it gives null, is it because the grpc classes don't have a bean? thanks