# How to create an entityManager without @Bean

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, entitymanager

I'm trying to create a [grpc client and server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76949476/how-to-create-a-repository-without-annotations/76949896?noredirect=1#comment135663075_76949896) but inside the endpoint of the grpc class it doesn't accept @Bean so I wanted to know how to create an entityManager property without @Bean or @Autowired

If anyone can help me I'll be grateful